# Will the clean-up logic still get called if an exception is thrown from within a using statement?

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, try-catch, using-statement

I have some questions about using the `using` keyword. I have the following code:

```
try {
   using (System.Net.WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) {
      throw new Exception("Example");
   }
} 

catch ( Exception ex ) { 
}
```

My question is, when the exception occurs will it close the connection? Or do I have to close the connection inside the catch?

Comment: The using will dispose (close) the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will close the connection.

The entire point of a `using` is that it will dispose the object when you leave the scope of the `using`, even if it is through an exception.

a `using` block is, under the hood, implemented using a `try/finally` block.

This is easy enough to test experimentally as well:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I was disposed!");
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (var foo = new Foo())
            throw new Exception("I'm mean");
    }
    catch { }
 }
```

And the output is:

> I was disposed!